# Why after each transaction rollback, the table size is increasing in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, rollback

I am running some tests on postgresql 9.6. I have created a table :

```
CREATE TABLE salary
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  employee_id numeric,
  salary_amount numeric,
  CONSTRAINT salary_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Then insert some data and rollback :

```
begin;
insert into salary (employee_id, salary_amount)
values 
(2,1000),(3,2000),(5,2000),(6,2000),(7,2000),(9,2000),(4,2000);

rollback;
```

After rolling back of this transaction the size of salary table is increasing but no records were created.

1. **Why after each transaction rollback the size of an empty table is increasing?**
2. **Does this affect the query performance?**

Comment: this beacuse the space used in transaction is allocated ..but should be reused   in the next.

Comment: Each time I run this transaction with rollback, the table size is increasing! where is the location of this used space?

Comment: should be the space needed  for the transaction (committed ) .. but with rollback the space is not reuse .. is resused after with others commit  .. normally ..

Comment: I don't know postgress, but under 'reorg postgress' i found pg_repack and the postgreess VACUUM-Statement, which should handle this unused space

Comment: @sciasEdge I do not commit anything. I run queries for several times to check avg execution time then rollback. so it should not use any space.

Answer (score 2):

The file became larger because the records were written to the table's file before the transaction was rolled back. They were not visible to other transactions even though they were in the file.

Query performance is affected by dead tuples in the file, because, put simply, queries may have to read past them when looking for active records. This is why PostgreSQL has an operation called "vacuuming" that cleans up unused data, freeing the space it occupies for new records.

Any halfway recent PostgreSQL version will vacuum your tables automatically when necessary. You can also force this using the VACUUM SQL command:

```
 VACUUM salary;
```

Or on the command line:

```
 vacuumdb -t salary database
```

You do not need to do this unless you have some seriously massive activity on the table, though. Please note that the file will not normally become smaller even after vacuuming: VACUUM does not move records around, so the file size is controlled by where the last active record is.